# Is there a utility to extract/compress files using any type of archiving algorithm?

Tags: command-line, archive, 7zip

Usually I use `tar` for ***.tar** archives, `zip/unzip` for ***.zip**, `7z` for ***.7z** , etc... Is there an über utility that combine all algorithms?

Here is pseudo usage of this utility:

Extracting:

```
$ unpack *.tar -d /home/c0rp/this_is_tar
$ unpack *.rar -d /home/c0rp/this_is_rar
$ unpack *.tar.gz -d /home/c0rp/this_is_targz
$ unpack *.zip -d /home/c0rp/this_is_zip
$ unpack *.7z -d /home/c0rp/this_is_7z
```

Compressing:

```
$ pack some_name.tar /home/c0rp/for_tar1 /home/c0rp/for_tar2
$ pack some_name.rar /home/c0rp/for_rar1 /home/c0rp/for_rar2
$ pack some_name.tar.gz /home/c0rp/for_targz1 /home/c0rp/for_targz2
$ pack some_name.zip /home/c0rp/for_zip1 /home/c0rp/for_zip2
$ pack some_name.7z /home/c0rp/for_zip1 /home/c0rp/for_7z
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just realized that 7-Zip (command `7z`) can do it. 7-Zip is able to extract and compress many types of archives. Here is a quote from `man 7z`:

```
DESCRIPTION
    7-Zip is a file archiver with the highest compression ratio. The pro-
    gram supports 7z (that implements LZMA compression algorithm), LZMA2,
    XZ, ZIP, Zip64, CAB, RAR (if the non-free p7zip-rar package is
    installed), ARJ, GZIP, BZIP2, TAR, CPIO, RPM, ISO, most filesystem
    images and DEB formats...
```

7-Zip can extract/compress archives and is detecting the compressing algorithm itself.

This should work as you are expecting:

Compressing

```
$ 7z a file.tar.gz file
$ 7z a file.zip file
$ 7z a file.7z file
$ 7z a file.gzip file
```

Extracting

```
$ 7z x file.tar.gz
$ 7z x file.zip
$ 7z x file.7z
$ 7z x file.gzip
```

---

Also here is a little test. Here I create five archives and give them different filename extensions.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ touch testfile
$ for alg in {zip,gzip,7z,tar.gz,rar};do 7z a testfile."$alg" testfile;done
$ ls testfile*
testfile.7z
testfile.gzip
testfile.rar
testfile.tar.gz
testfile.zip
```

Now to detect the compressing algorithm, I will use the `binwalk` utility.

```
$ for arch in testfile.*;do binwalk "$arch" | sed -n '4p' | awk {'print $3'};done
7-zip
gzip
7-zip
gzip
Zip
```

Comment: Are you sure it detects the compression/file type based on the filename 'extension'? I think it just reads the magic header like the `file` command does.

Comment: @gertvdijk May be I'm wrong. If you can proof it, feel free to edit answer

Comment: @gertvdijk I think it will use magic header, but firstly it will read file extension

Comment: There you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9147636/

Comment: @gertvdijk, interesting. Before posting I test it, but I test it using 7z only

Comment: @gertvdijk http://paste.ubuntu.com/9147803/. Here is my test. I remove my suggestion about extension from answer, until I understand how it is working

Comment: Is `binwalk` reporting two 7-Zip files because you don't have `p7zip-rar` installed? I would've expected `7z` to at least give a warning if that happened.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`

Answer (score 2):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/dtrx

> intelligently extract multiple archive types

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install dtrx
```

Homepage: http://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/