# Why I can't uncompress a .bz2 file using tar?

Tags: command-line, tar, bzip2

So I have this wikipedia dump sized at about 10gb and named as "enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2".
I have been trying the following commands in the terminal to unzip the dump:

```
tar jxf enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

And

```
tar xvf enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

But both of them returns the following error

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
```

Comment: arun run the following command and past the out put **"file enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"**

Comment: [This Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/552188/is-there-a-utility-to-extract-compress-files-using-any-type-of-archiving-algorit) can help, use `7z` util for extracting everything

Comment: I notice you say this is a huge file - so another things you might want to do is pipe it into something, bzcat enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 | someotherprogram

Comment: @nwaltham: You'd have my upvote if you made that an answer.

Comment: Because tar extracts tar files, and it's not a tar file?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can't use the `tar` command because the archive isn't a .tar.* file. To uncompress a bzip2 file, use the following command (this won't preserve the original .bz2 file):

```
bzip2 -d enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

If you want to extract it and keep the original, run this command:

```
bzip2 -dk enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/480950/how-to-decompress-a-bz2-file

Comment: Or use `bunzip2`.

Comment: @immibis Either way works.:)

Answer (score 21):

Just use `bunzip2`:

```
bunzip2 enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

And if its a `gzip` commpressed file:

```
gunzip enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.gz
```